# set up range on EF5 CF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a class that is going to be a part of database later. What i want to do it set up Range for a property in the class. let me explain. I have a class named as Rack`
.......
class Rack
    {
        public int RackID { get; set; }
        public string RackName { get; set; }

```
    public int SpaceUnits { get; set; } //RackSpace is predefined for every Rack. i.e. 40Units.
}`.....
```

Now where it says SpaceUnits I want to used a ranged Value 1-40. Is it possible? or i have to use a Default value i.e. [Defaultvalue(40)]
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a RangeAttribute

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute.aspx

```
 [Range(1, 40)]
 public int SpaceUnits { get; set; }
```

As far as I know it is no restriction on database level, but is is used in all EF validation routines.

Answer (score 1):

YOu can use Range for that

```
[Range(1, 40)]
public int SpaceUnits { get; set; }
```